# Which macOS VNC client can connect to the default Ubuntu VNC server?

Tags: remote-desktop, screen-sharing, compatibility

A few machines running Ubuntu 18.04 have to be accessed remotely through VNC.

On Ubuntu, I can use Remmina Remote Desktop Client to connect to the VNC server. The VNC server on Ubuntu is setup via the default **Desktop Sharing**:

[image: Desktop Sharing in Ubuntu]

I want to connect to that Ubuntu session via VNC from a macOS client.

I tried using the ["hidden" default VNC client](https://til.hashrocket.com/posts/69cbe9b2c3-how-to-use-the-hidden-vnc-client-in-mac-osx) by going through Finder and using <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd>, and:

```
vnc://ubuntu-server-hostname.local
```

and:

```
vnc://ubuntu-server-hostname.local:5900
```

and

```
vnc://{UBUNTU-SERVER-IP}:5900
```

yet it states that version of the server cannot be identified. I am assuming the the default client works only for macOS servers.

Is there, and if so which, a VNC server can connect to an Linux server? I prefer the solution to be open source or freeware. A paid solution is not an option for me, yet feel free to name it to give a working solution.

Comment: Doesn't work with Mac OS X Mojave & Ubuntu 18.04. According Screen Sharing, the ubuntu software is now incompatible

Answer (score 3):

There exist many modern VNC clients for macOS that supports connecting to Linux servers. Free ones include [TigerVNC](https://tigervnc.org) and [RealVNC Viewer](https://www.realvnc.com/en/connect/download/viewer/macos/).

Comment: Both clients do not reckognize the security setting: `Unable to connect to VNC Server using your chosen security setting` or in case of tigerVnc: `No matching security types`.

Comment: You can solve this by running the following on the server: “gsettings set org.gnome.Vino require-encryption false”. If you prefer not doing that, post your VNC server configuration details so that we can see how you have it configured.

Comment: I confirm that after setting this variable to false I was able to connect to the Ubuntu 18 server with both RealVNC Viewer and the integrated macOS Screen Sharing application.

Comment: Setting `require-encryption` to `false` is a very bad idea as it means the data in transit to your server (including credentials) is sent in clear.

Comment: I thought it was obvious that it disables encryption - but yes, ofcourse. It doesn't mean it is a bad idea per say - rather it means that you should wrap the connection in encryption if you're working on an exposed network (such as connecting to a server over the internet). You can do that by for example using an SSH tunnel or various styles of tunnel/VPN programs. In my experience, VNC is usually used on local network servers in home networks where the exposure is very limited.